# How could I create object from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to use loop to create json object from array which has many elements

How could I return this object from this array?

My array:

```
[
"text 1",
"text 2",
"text 3"
]
```

My object I want to return:

```
return [
  {
    json: {
      message: "text 1"
    } 
  },
  {
    json: {
      message: "text 2"
    }
  },
  {
    json: {
      message: "text 3"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: i see no json ...

Comment: consider using `Array.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const input = [
  "text 1",
  "text 2",
  "text 3"
];

const output = input.map((item) => ({
  json: {
    message: item
  }
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [ "text 1", "text 2", "text 3" ];
let response = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   response.push({
    json: {
      message: arr[i];
    } 
  });
}

return response;
```

While the above code helps you, it is generally a good practice to write about what attempts you made to solve the problem and if you encountered any challenges while doing so

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through the array while pushing to an object:

```js
const originalArray = [
"text 1",
"text 2",
"text 3"
]

let newArray = []

for (const arrayItem of originalArray) {
    newArray.push({json: {message: arrayItem}})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be a good use case for using map. Map allows you to iterate across an array populated by the result of the function passed to it. In this case the function would be creating a new object with a field "json" that has another object within with the field "message".

```
let arr  =[
"text 1",
"text 2",
"text 3"
];
let jsonArr = arr.map(message=>{
    return ({json:{message}});
});
```